# Arduino Mega Class redefinition error

Tags: c++, arduino

I have the basic simple LCD Hello World sketch:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

void setup() {
 lcd.begin(16, 2);
 lcd.print("hello, world!");
}

void loop() {
     lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
     lcd.print(millis()/1000);
}
```

I get the redefinition error that clearly indicates that I have two (or more) definitions of the Print class, and I probably need to add an

```
#ifndef Print_h 
#define Print_h
```

How can I tell by the following error message which file(s) is missing the if define?

Compiling 'LCDtest' for 'Arduino Mega (ATmega1280)

> Stream.h:In file included from 
>   HardwareSerial.h:from 
>   arduino.h:from 
>   LCDtest.ino:from 
>   Print.h:39: error: redefinition of 'class Print' 
>   Print.h:39: error: previous definition of 'class Print' 
>   Stream.h:In file included from 
>   HardwareSerial.h:from 
>   Arduino.h:from 
>   LiquidCrystal.cpp:from 
>   Print.h:39: error: redefinition of 'class Print' 
>   Print.h:39: error: previous definition of 'class Print' 
>   Error compiling

Comment: Does the installed Print.h file have the #ifndef directive?